# SQL Help - Summarising tagging data by value

Tags: sql

I am trying to add some tags to a dataset using SQL and then summarising by those tags.

Eg If I have a data Set like this:

[image]

1. I would like to parse the values in the "Meal" field and extract out some tags using simple logic. The catch is that each line could contain multiple tags
   Eg for Order 1 - it is both in the VeganFiendly category and the Softdrink Category
   [image]
2. I would then like to Summarise it by Category

[image]

**Potential approach**
The recommendation I received was to Split the Meal field into seperate lines so Each OrderItem is its own line which I can do - however I am not sure how to summarise this down into the format of Item 2

Any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: hi I have done the split mentioned above - but its not clear how to summarise

Comment: what version of T-SQL are you in?

Answer (score 0):

to use STRING_SPLIT table valued function you must be in at least SQL Server 2016

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```
declare @mytable table (OrderID varchar(20), CustomerID varchar(20), Meal varchar(1000), MealCount smallint, Tags varchar(1000))

insert into @mytable
values 
 ('Order1','Customer1','Salad,Coke',1,'VeganFriendly,Softdrink')
,('Order2','Customer2','Hotdog,Onions,Chips,Milkshake',1,'MeatEater,ContainsMilk')
,('Order3','Customer3','Burger,Beef,Chips,Coke',1,'MeatEater,Softdrink')


;with cte_split_data as (
select * from @mytable
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',')
   )
select value Category, count(OrderID) NumberOfOrders from cte_split_data
group by value
```